# AngularJS Satellizer OAuth2 with UI-Router callback route

Tags: angularjs, oauth, azure-devops, satellizer, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to implement Visual Studio Online rest API authorization using OAuth2 in my angular app.

For easy OAuth2 implementation, I wanted to use Satellizer module (https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/).

This is how I have configured `$authProvider`

```
$authProvider.oauth2({
            name: 'vso',
            url: '/oauth/callback',
            scope: ['vso.build_execute', 'vso.chat_manage', 'vso.code_manage', 'vso.packaging_manage', 'vso.project_manage', 'vso.release_execute', 'vso.work_write'],
            scopeDelimiter: '%20',
            state : 'ngApp',
            defaultUrlParams: ['response_type', 'client_id', 'scope', 'redirect_uri', 'state'],
            clientId: '{client_id}',
            responseType: 'Assertion',
            redirectUri: '{redirect_uri}',
            authorizationEndpoint: 'https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/oauth2/authorize',
        });
```

Now, the problem is I only have UI router in place for my app and I can't configure app on my Visual Studio Online portal in a such a way that it redirects `code` and `state` to UI Router / angular router style callback URL (i.e. http://sitename/#/oauth/callback). Visual Studio does not accept `#` in redirect uris.

I can not turn on html5mode because my user might refresh the page and app will lose the state. I don't want to configure backend to re-route such requests to root of an app.

How can I implement OAuth2.0 authorization for Visual Studio Team Services?

Comment: How did you implement this finally?